# C++11 std::shared_ptr works fine, but boost::shared_ptr crashes, what can cause this?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, c++11, shared-ptr

I have a multithreaded program (can't reproduce it here -- it's thousands of lines) that works perfectly fine with C++11 (GCC 4.7.3) every single time, but which crashes when using C++03 (with Boost 1.53).

Specifically, I'm substituting `std::atomic` and `std::shared_ptr` with `boost::atomic` and `boost::shared_ptr` in my code (and compiling it with `-std=c++03` in GCC). The code is otherwise the same.

However, the C++03/Boost version crashes or loops forever. When it crashes, it does so inside here:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff4dc2700 (LWP 4065)]
0x000000000043d0c8 in boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release() ()
```

The disassembly for this seems to be:

```
(gdb) disas 0x000000000043d0c8
Dump of assembler code for function _ZN5boost6detail15sp_counted_base7releaseEv:
   0x000000000043d0b0 <+ 0>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x8],rbp
   0x000000000043d0b5 <+ 5>:    mov    ebp,0xffffffff
   0x000000000043d0ba <+10>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x10],rbx
   0x000000000043d0bf <+15>:    mov    eax,ebp
   0x000000000043d0c1 <+17>:    sub    rsp,0x18
   0x000000000043d0c5 <+21>:    mov    rbx,rdi
=> 0x000000000043d0c8 <+24>:    lock xadd DWORD PTR [rdi+0x8],eax
   0x000000000043d0cd <+29>:    cmp    eax,0x1
   0x000000000043d0d0 <+32>:    je     0x43d0e8 <_ZN5boost6detail15sp_counted_base7releaseEv+56>
   0x000000000043d0d2 <+34>:    mov    rbx,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
   0x000000000043d0d7 <+39>:    mov    rbp,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10]
   0x000000000043d0dc <+44>:    add    rsp,0x18
   0x000000000043d0e0 <+48>:    ret
```

I see `rdi` has the value `0x3f9dafee19598306`, which looks wrong and is misaligned (the latter probably being the cause of the crash).

I've never seen any problems on the C++11 version (I've tested it both on Visual Studio 2013 on Windows and the current GCC on Linux), yet this happens every single time I run it on the C++03 version, so I doubt it's a race condition in my code, or I would've seen it in the C++11 version by now.

So I'm a little confused -- what difference between `boost::shared_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` could possibly be causing this?

---

#### Update:

I'm using `make_shared` as well... and it seems like when I avoid using `make_shared`, the C++11 version infinite-loops on Linux too (still works fine on Windows). Not sure what that implies though.

Comment: the first google hit for the seg faulting function is [this](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4415) - does that seem similar? (it makes mention of the line of code `if( atomic_exchange_and_add( &use_count_, -1 ) == 1 )` which looks eerily similar to the disassembly)

Comment: @user3125280: The problem does look similar, but it seems like that one was resolved as "invalid"? I'm not sure how it helps...

Comment: whoops - still is there a possibility of a similar error with recursive destruction of a large object causing a stack overflow?

Comment: could you post code showing the difference in shared_ptr construction using make_shared vs in the c++03 code?

Comment: @user3125280: I can't rule it out, I'll take a look. But shouldn't a stack overflow trigger an error? And the code is almost exactly the same: `new_vdeps = detail::shared_ptr<Dependencies>(new Dependencies());` vs. `new_vdeps = detail::make_shared<Dependencies>();` where `detail::make_shared` and `detail::shared_ptr` are imported in the `detail` namespace using `using std::shared_ptr;` or `using boost::shared_ptr;` etc.

Comment: stack overflow causes segfualt (the stack pointer being now in the wrong area of memory) - rdi's value comes from accessing the shared_ptr's use_count_ where the ptr's address is passed on the stack. I don't really have the inside knowledge to help though.

Comment: @user3125280: Yeah that's what I mean, I should be getting a segfault in the case of a stack overflow but I'm not...

Comment: "`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault`" (this was the problem in the link I suggested - oddly it only seems to happen in one version of your program, and I have no idea why)

Comment: @user3125280: Oh but the segfault there is at the `lock xadd` instruction, I think it's due to a misalignment. There's no stack pointer being used at that instruction.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45526/discussion-between-user3125280-and-mehrdad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the problem.

It was, in fact, not with `boost::shared_ptr`, but with `boost::atomic` elsewhere in my code.

`boost::atomic` **does not automatically zero-initialize its value**!

Comment: Neither does [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic) - so this cannot be the difference between the two versions.

Comment: @Casey: Are you sure? I see `_Atomic() _NOEXCEPT
  : _My_val()
  { /* default constructor */
  }`

Comment: [Straight from the horses mouth](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html) "shared_ptr atomic access ... Partial [implementation]". Since it says in the same document that it uses boost::share_ptr code, maybe there are problems there (which libstdc++ programmers may have changed).

Comment: @user3125280: I think by "atomic access" they might mean `std::atomic_xxx(shared_ptr *, shared_ptr)`, not what I was using.

Comment: C++11 §29.6.5/4 specifies that `std::atomic` type `A` must have a default constructor declared as `A::A() noexcept = default;` and that "*Effects:* leaves the atomic object in the uninitialized state." The code excerpt you quoted appears to value-initialize the atomic type; it would be unwise to write your program to depend on behavior that contradicts the standard.

Comment: @Casey: OK well I don't read the standard when I code, I just look at the implementation in front of me.